# JSF - fields not initialized at @PostConstruct

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, postconstruct

Hellow I am trying to load a jsf page depending on a parameter I pass from a previous page.

I am passing the parameter in the url and trying to read it in the @PostConstruct method of the second page's managed bean to determine what to display in the second page.

The parameter I pass is already defined in the second page's managed bean as the following:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.displayText}")
String displayText;
```

but the problem is that when I try to read the value of displayText in the @PostConstruct method it is still set to null.

I noticed that all fields in the managed bean are still set to null at the time @PostConstruct method executes.

any help please, is there any other method I should be using other than @PostConstruct?

Comment: how do you pass paraeter to new page? it's important. because e.g.         <h:button value="GO" outcome="home?displayText=test"/> is will work. but <h:commandButton value="GO" action="home?displayText=test"/> will not work.

Comment: Simply means the value was not set. You're omitting a lot of context here: What kind of bean is your backing bean (cannot a CDI bean)? How are you passing the variable from the previous page? Everything the bean needs is supposed to be available as at `@PostConstruct`, so something is seriously wrong with your setup

Comment: the application I am building is not purely JSF, I am using Jdeveloper to build a java ee web application, which includes JSF, JSP and servlets. My web pages are .jspx could this have anything to do with not having proper setup?

Comment: see this link please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310094/jsf-managed-bean-fields-not-initialized-at-postconstruct